# html button has excess whitespace above due to text content

Tags: html, css

So I have the following code below.

```css
.innerDiv1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  padding-right: 5px
}

.innerDiv2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.inner2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  
}

.rect {
  width: 0%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12;
}

.sendreceiveBtn {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  max-height: 25px;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="inlineItems" id="progBtnBar">
    <div class="innerDiv1">
      <div class="inner2">
        <div id="myProgress">
          <div class="rect">0%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="innerDiv2">
      <button class=sendreceiveBtn>Transmit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to line up a button vertically with another div, with both as inline-block inside another div, so they end up next to eachother, preferably the exact same size. However, something about the button is pushing it down a bit. Nothing I have done so far has been able to change this EXCEPT for increasing the font of the text in the button. What is making this space, and how can I get these to line up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the culprit:

```
.rect {
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: That seems to do it for this example. Funny though, I'm almost certain that I added this as part of an attempt to solve this problem previously, because my css was pretty basic when I first encountered this issue. Ah well, its solved now, fixed both my little example, and the actual code where Im having the issue, thanks.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and line-height is not the culprit. Unless the line height is treated differently for buttons. I have text on one side, button on the other that is style exactly like text, down to padding, margin, outline, etc. And the button still sits slightly below the text.

Comment: @Mig did you post a question? It would be easier to troubleshoot if we saw your code.

Comment: Thanks @bprdev ! I expected to do this after I investigated enough. Since the question was related, I hoped somebody here would have the answer. At the end, during my investigations, I've realised that having the parent as `display: flex;` would fix this and remove the extra top space. Not always a convenient solution which is why I would not create an official answer. But still, helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Vertical align allows multiple siblings to share the same vertical position.

```
.innerDiv1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  padding-right: 5px
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.innerDiv2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You can see a working example in the following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gkotxdt7/

Answer (score 1):

Replace Your existing CSS with below:

```
    .innerDiv1 {   display: table-cell;   width: 45%;   border-right: 1px solid;   padding-right: 5px; vertical-align: middle; }

.innerDiv2 {   display: table-cell;   width: 45%;   padding-left: 5px; vertical-align: middle; }

.inner2 {   border: 1px solid black;    }

.rect {   width: 0%;   height: 20px;   background-color: #4CAF50;   text-align: center;   line-height: 30px;   color: black;   font-size: 12; }

.sendreceiveBtn {  min-height: 25px; width: 100%; font-size: 12px; height: auto;    }

#progBtnBar{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; }
```

Thats it. It will resolve the issue.